# How to design an analog circuit that turns on a dripping irrigation systems?

Tags: analog, timer, 555, homework, delay

```
I am asked to design a DC power supplied irrigation system that turns on for 30 mins every 6 hours. It's a design question using Pspice. No budget taken into consideration. It's an academic question for my electronics lab project. I might use a battery as the power source.
```

**Only analog components are allowed. We're allowed to only use the 555 IC. No Arduino or any other IC.**

**Just to clarify, these are the constraints required:**

```
> 1. You are not allowed to use prefabricated logic gates or prefabricated ICs for electronic components (for example, if you want to use a full-wave bridge rectifier, you have to build it using diodes and you cannot use an IC that is a full-wave bridge rectifier).  
> 2. You are also not allowed to use Arduino or any other controller or microcontroller that requires programming the commands. The circuit
> has to be purely analog not digital.
```

I thought about building a timer delay relay circuit that turns on the irrigation systems for 30 mins. The problem is how to make it wait for 6 hours so it could turn on for 30 mins and the cycle goes on. I thought about building another 555 timer circuit that is connected to trigger a MOSFET so it could turn on the other timer.

It's preferred to help me design the circuit using a 555 timer.

Comment: A mechanical timer perhaps?

Comment: @SamihHajjIbrahim - Hi, I have moved important information about the project constraints, which you put into the comments, into the question text. On Stack Exchange we should always aim to make the question as complete as possible, and not rely on people reading comments in order to "fill in the gaps". I have used your own words, where possible, when copying the information into the question. If you want to change or clarify further, please [edit] the question. Thanks.

Comment: A 555 timer is an IC and has some analog as well as digital parts. So a circuit with one or two 555 is not completely analog .

Comment: @Uwe - Agreed. FYI the OP clarified in a comment (which I have now moved into the question) that the 555, while obviously an IC, is allowed in the project constraints.

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for the help and clarification. I'm still new to stackexchange. Still learning my way through it.

Comment: @SamihHajjIbrahim - Hi, I see that your question was closed as "opinion-based" by community voting. Voters added no additional explanation. As far as I can tell, the concern (to avoid site members wasting time writing answers which don't meet the constraints from your teacher) is the meaning of "*Only analog components are allowed*", yet you say that the 555 IC is allowed, despite having (arguably) some internal digital functionality. Can you clarify more? For example, using a MOSFET to switch an output is arguably digital (i.e. on/off). Are you sure *that* is allowed? Do you see the concerns?

Answer (score 2):

The limits you have stated make this sound like a homework task.  Is it?

With no uC, a "normal" way would be an oscillator and counter.  For accuracy, everything you need is in a CD4060.  With less accuracy, a CMOS 555 plus a CD4017 will work.

Does building a flipflop out of discrete transistors count as an "analog" solution?  If so, there are many ways to do this.

How accurate do the two timing parameters have to be?  +/-10 minutes over 6 hours is less than +/-3%, a difficult thing to do with an R-C or current-source-plus-C timer.  One problem is the capacitor value is so large that its leakage current is equal to or even greater than the charging current.  And then there is the input bias current of whatever is determining the trip point, usually an analog comparator of some kind.

Example:  12 V, one time constant circuit.  For six hours, R x C = 360.  With a 1 M resistor, the charging current is  12 uA at the start of the cycle (not very much), and only 4 uA at the trip point.  The required capacitor is 360 uF, large enough that its leakage current can be a significant percentage of these values.  also, that leakage current varies a lot with temperature.  With a 10 M resistor the capacitor is much smaller, but so are the timing currents in the circuit.

Please add more details about the constraints on the design.

Comment: Yes , this is a small part of the project which I am facing a problem with. I can't use any flip flop. Yes I am aware of the fact that the timer could not be so accurate, but I guess that as long it's not a big difference, then it's fine. The only thing stated is that I have to use analog components and no sensors or so, also it's dc power supplied, I am free to assume anything I want( power rating)

Comment: A flipflop is a digital circuit, a counter build from flipflops is undoubtedly a digital circuit. If discrete or integrated transistors are used does not matter.

Comment: There is a flipflop inside a 555.

Comment: At some point the circuit turns on and off a valve, so there is an on/off digital signal.  The limits on what is and is not allowed to generate that signal still are not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the old fashioned way. Use a motor and a gear reducer. Place two limit switches on a radius of the gear reducer output. First switch starts a relay, second switch turns off the relay. The timing is determined by rotational speed and placement of switches.

You can work out for yourself the motor speed, gear ratio and switch placement.

Comment: This is not the purpose of the project. If I could I would've , but it's not convincing to use motor speed and these things in an electronics oriented course.

Comment: The question is then a moving target as there are new answers you make new exclusions.

Comment: I said that it's DC power supplied and I used tags related to the projects' topics so you could know what I am taking about. Besides, I didn't think of doing it using mechanics.

Comment: I can see what you are wanting. Is ok. However rotating machines, switches and relays have been part of electrical/electronics for many years. Hopefully others will do the design for you.